# Excel - Duplicates in column matched to row duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If there are duplicates in column A then the data should match in column B. I am looking for a formula that returns a yes/no value if all values in column B match according to the value in column A. Here is a sample of what I am looking for:

```
Column A
55555
55555
66666
66666
66666

Column B
Paid
Paid
Paid 
Unpaid
Unpaid

Column C
Yes
Yes
No
No
No
```

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIF/COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1),"Yes","no")
```

If they are all the same for the given Number in Column A then the two will be equal, if not the will be different.

[image]